# Main Menu Hover is Always White

Tags: menus, css, links

My Main Menu Hover color is always white. I used to be able to just change it in the customizer but that stopped working so I've tried every kind of CSS I can find, gone through inspecting it, tried plugins and still not sure how to override it. Not sure if anyone knows how to help? I'm not very familiar with CSS, so I probably just did something wrong, but I tried deleting everything in my custom CSS and that did not work to reverse it either. Thanks!

[my site](https://cabinpuppets.com)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Elementor is setting the hover color for all links on the page to `#5E6462`, which is hard to read against the background color of the nav menu.

Somewhere within Elementor the color is being set; that will need to be changed.